# Module Inside ToBoxes or MakeBoxes

Tags: dynamic, scoping, inputfield

Does someone mind explaining why Module doesn't seem to work while inside `ToBoxes` or `MakeBoxes`.

```
SetAttributes[AutoInputField, HoldAllComplete];
AutoInputField /: MakeBoxes[AutoInputField[
    list_: {}, displayNum_: 3, imageSize_: 100], form_] :=
  ToBoxes@Module[{x = "default"},
    x = "default";
    Column[{
      InputField[Dynamic@x, String, ContinuousAction -> True, 
       ImageSize -> imageSize],
      Dynamic@x
      }
     ]
    ];
AutoInputField[]
AutoInputField[]
```

Ideally x should be set to `"default"`, but as of right now x isn't taking on any value.  Surprisingly `Module` is successful at scoping the different value because the two `InputField`s values don't change interactively.

I am looking for a way to modify/set the value of x inside the `Module`.

Comment: Someone has point this out to you in one of the previous question but let me quote John Fultz: "Module variables should never appear inside Dynamics or Manipulates internal to that Module.". That's ofcourse a side note.

Comment: @Kuba `DynamicModule` works.  Although it works, I am just assuming that is the technique that is best advised.

Comment: I have found the link that you are referring to [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcLM5xDRqHE/V0FghIKeO_QJ) Quit useful.  What do you think would be most appropriate: you posting a response, me posting a response, or closing/deleting the question?

Comment: Remark about `DynamicModule` was only a side not. I must admit my I have not focus well on your question so I'm not going to answer :) If you've solved your issue it is encouraged to self-answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears using `DynamicModule` solves the issue quite well.

```
SetAttributes[AutoInputField, HoldAllComplete];
AutoInputField /: MakeBoxes[AutoInputField[
    list_: {}, displayNum_: 3, imageSize_: 100], form_] :=
  ToBoxes@DynamicModule[{x = "default"},
    x = "default";
    Column[{
      InputField[Dynamic@x, String, ContinuousAction -> True, 
       ImageSize -> imageSize],
      Dynamic@x
      }
     ]
    ];
AutoInputField[]
AutoInputField[]
```

Although John Fultz's answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcLM5xDRqHE/V0FghIKeO_QJ) was not about `Module` values it appears his rules there hold true for this question also.

Comment: This is exactly what `DynamicModule` was designed to do, and it is exactly what I've warned against where `Module` is concerned.  In 9.0.1, the code in your question would have colored red to warn you, except for a bug that causes it to not color for `Dynamic@x` (as opposed to `Dynamic[x]`).

Comment: Incidentally, I've fixed the lack of proper syntax highlighting on `Dynamic@x`.  In my development version, the non-`DynamicModule` version now highlights the `x` red in all appropriate places.